# Subsetting Across Data Frames Using dplyr in R

Tags: r, time-series, subset, dplyr, apply

and thanks in advance for looking.

I have a data frame of Events(EV):

```
Event_ID | Person_ID | Start_Period | End_Period | Event_Type
------------------------------------------------------------
A        | Person1   | 1            | 9          | Assessment
B        | Person1   | 2            | 9          | Activity
C        | Person1   | 3            | 6          | Assessment
D        | Person2   | 3            | 6          | Activity
E        | Person3   | 7            | 13         | Assessment
```

And I have a data frame of Person-Periods (PP)

```
Person_ID | Period
----------------------
Person1   | 1
Person1   | 2
Person1   | 3
Person2   | 1
Person2   | 2
Person2   | 3
Person3   | 1
Person3   | 2
Person3   | 3
```

I want to find out for each period, how many **activities or assessments were on-going during the period**. For example if an event for Person1 in EV had a start period of 5 and end period of 10, then this event should show up in 5,6,7,8,9,10 in PP. The result would look like this:

```
Person_ID | Period | ActivitiesFreq | AssessmentsFreq
----------------------------------------------
Person1   | 1      | 0              | 1
Person1   | 2      | 1              | 1
Person1   | 3      | 1              | 2
Person2   | 1      | 0              | 0
Person2   | 2      | 0              | 0
Person2   | 3      | 1              | 0
Person3   | 1      | 0              | 0
Person3   | 2      | 0              | 0
Person3   | 3      | 0              | 0
```

At the moment I'm using a for loop - which is slow.And I'm resisting a join because the full dataset has hundreds and thousands of data. I've tried using mutate from the dplyr package:

```
mutate(PP,SUM(EV$Person_ID==Person_ID,EV$Start_Period<=Period,EV$End_Period>=Period)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I'm open to using other packages - I think I don't quite understand something about the way mutate works

Comment: @Arun Apologies, original data truncated so should now be consistent. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (current devel version). I'm using it for the new `on=` feature that allows joins without having to set keys:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
ans = setDT(df2)[df1, .(Period, Event_Type, 
                        isBetween = Period %between% c(Start_Period, End_Period)), 
                by = .EACHI, on = "Person_ID", nomatch = 0L]

dcast(ans, Person_ID + Period ~ Event_Type, fun.aggregate = sum)
# Using 'isBetween' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#    Person_ID Period Activity Assessment
# 1:   Person1      1        0          1
# 2:   Person1      2        1          1
# 3:   Person1      3        1          2
# 4:   Person2      1        0          0
# 5:   Person2      2        0          0
# 6:   Person2      3        1          0
# 7:   Person3      1        0          0
# 8:   Person3      2        0          0
# 9:   Person3      3        0          0
```

---

How it works:

- `setDT()` converts a *data.frame* to *data.table* in-place (by reference).
- `setDT(df2)[df1, on = "Person_ID"]` performs a *join* operation on column `Person_ID`. For each row in `df1`, the corresponding matching rows in `df2` are computed, and all columns corresponding to those matching rows are extracted.
- `setDT(df2)[df1, on = "Person_ID", nomatch = 0L]`, as you might have guessed only returns matching rows, and leaves out those rows of `Person_ID` in `df1` where there is no match in `df2`.
- The `by = .EACHI` part is quite useful and powerful argument. It helps to compute the expression we provide in `j`, the second argument within `[]`, for each row in `df1`.

  For example, consider the 2nd row of `df1`. Joining on `Person_ID`, it matches with rows 1,2,3 of `df2`. And `by = .EACHI` will execute the expression provided within `.()`, which will return `Period = 1,2,3`, `Event_Type = "Activity"`and `isBetween = FALSE,TRUE,TRUE`. `Event_Type` is recycled to fit the length of the longest vector (= 3).

  > Essentially, we are *joining* and *computing* at the same time. This is a feature (only?) in *data.table*, where *joins* are considered as extensions of *subset* operations. Since we can compute while subsetting and grouping, we can do exactly the same while *joining* as well. This is both *fast* **and** *memory efficient as the entire join doesn't have to be materialised.

  To understand it better, try computing what `j` expression will result in for the last row.

  Then, have a look at `ans`, and the result should be obvious.
- Then we've one last step to do and that is to count the number of `Activity` and `Assessment` for each `Person_ID, Period` and have them as separate columns. This can be done in one step using `dcast` function.

  The formula implies that for each `Person_ID, Period`, we'd like to `sum()` the values of `inBetween`, as a separate column, for each unique value of `Event_Type`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come up with a way to do this without joining datasets.  Here is a **dplyr**-based solution using `left_join` to join the datasets first (I took only the three columns from `EV` needed for the task).

Once the dataset are joined, you can just group the dataset by `Person_ID` and calculate the cumulative sum of the two types of events.  I threw in an `arrange` in case the real dataset wasn't in order by `Period` within `Person_ID` and removed the `Event_Type` column within `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
PP %>% 
    left_join(., select(EV, -Event_ID, -End_Period), by = c("Person_ID", "Period" = "Start_Period")) %>%
    group_by(Person_ID) %>%
    arrange(Period) %>%
    mutate(ActivitiesFreq = cumsum(Event_Type == "Activity" & !is.na(Event_Type)),
            AssessmentFreq = cumsum(Event_Type == "Assessment" & !is.na(Event_Type)),
            Event_Type = NULL)

Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
Groups: Person_ID

  Person_ID Period ActivitiesFreq AssessmentFreq
1   Person1      1              0              1
2   Person1      2              1              1
3   Person1      3              1              2
4   Person2      1              0              0
5   Person2      2              0              0
6   Person2      3              1              0
7   Person3      1              0              0
8   Person3      2              0              0
9   Person3      3              0              0
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a potential solution:

1. Left Join PP and EV (dplyr::left_join) on Person_ID and Period
2. Group by Person and period dplyr::group_by(Person_ID , Period)
3. Count the number of values using dplyr::summarise()

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure how this would work for on-going activities. E.g. if an activity runs from period 5 to 10, it should show up in PP for person months 5,6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: Thanks again for your solution! Is there another way that doesn't use a join? The table are of c. 200,000 rows each, giving a significant sized data frame that's going to be hard to handle. Thank you!

Comment: Fyi, for steps 2&3 you can count with `count` or `group_by`+`tally` in a dplyr chain.